# Including template .phtml between HEAD tags in magento

Tags: magento

I need in including some my `.phtml` template between tags

```
<head> </head>
```

My template generates some JS code with PHP therefore I need in `.phtml` template instead simple

```
<action method="addJs"><script>theme/script.js </script> </action>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Add to your xml:

```
<reference name="head">
    <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/script.js</name><params/></action>
</reference>
```

And add your script to `skin/frontend/[template]/[package]/js/script.js`